# Smart pointers and stack objects

Tags: segmentation-fault, stack, smart-pointers

I've read a few guides about smart pointers, and I think I understand the hang of it (no pun intended), but there's something that still bothers me about it.

Smart pointers are intended to work with pointers to data allocated on the heap using new, and once the smart pointer goes out of scope its destructor would deallocate the information the pointer points to. However, suppose I made a mistake and made the smart pointer point to an object allocated on the stack instead of on the heap. In this case I would get a nasty segmentation fault error, because I would try to use delete on a stack object.

To illustrate the problem, here are two code snippets. For this demonstration I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327248/Understanding-Implementing-Smart-Pointer-in-C) implementation for smart pointers. First, the proper way to use a smart pointer

```
int main(void)
{
  int my_num = 17;
  int *p = new int(my_num);
  MyAuto_Ptr<int> p2(p);

  return 0;
}
```

and here's the buggy version, with a pointer to a stack object, which causes a segmentation fault.

```
int main(void)
{
  int my_num = 17;
  int *p = &my_num;
  MyAuto_Ptr<int> p2(p);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to alert the user if a smart pointer points to a stack object?

Comment: Replace "which causes a segmentation fault" with "which invokes undefined behavior". Just like `delete p`.

Answer (score 3):

> First, the proper way to use a smart pointer

No, this is *not* the proper way to use a smart pointer.

The whole idea of using a smart pointer is that you *never* create a "raw" pointer in the first place. So your proper way would look like this:

```
 MyAuto_ptr<int> p(new int(my_num));
```

> Is there any way to alert the user if a smart pointer points to a stack object?

There is no general way to do this, but a system specific runtime check may be possible.

However, when you avoid "raw" pointers, attempt to initialize a smart pointer with a stack object will *immediately* stick out: without thinking, you can tell this is wrong:

```
 MyAuto_ptr<int> p(&my_num);
```